# React Transition Group page transition

Tags: reactjs, next.js, gsap, react-transition-group

I'm trying to replicate a similar page transition effect as here: https://zajno.com/. So far, so good. I've manage to get quite far with the effect itself, however, the way I set up everything now, React Transition Group creates a clone of the new page and overlays that with the the new page. Of course, I don’t want this duplicate. I want to have the old page and on top mounts the new page, then the old page unmounts. Here’s my codesandbox: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/react-transition-group-wp425n?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt9ycgj000073b6edatsxft5%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt9ycgj000023b6eydzfbaeu%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt9ycgj000043b6e8kievirk%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt9ycgj000063b6ewraqt6tz%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clt9ycgj000023b6eydzfbaeu%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt9ycgj000023b6eydzfbaeu%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clt9ycgj000063b6ewraqt6tz%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt9ycgj000053b6ean7h1okn%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt9ycgj000063b6ewraqt6tz%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt9ycgj000053b6ean7h1okn%2522%257D%252C%2522clt9ycgj000043b6e8kievirk%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt9ycgj000043b6e8kievirk%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt9ycgj000033b6eqx32krtp%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt9ycgj000033b6eqx32krtp%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt9yeq1g009w3b6eitilifeb%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clt9yeq2t002ndage8mq47qiw%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

```
<SwitchTransition mode="in-out">
  <Transition key={pathname} timeout={1200} unmountOnExit>
    {(state) => (
      <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 h-full w-full overflow-hidden">
        <div
          ref={ref}
          className={`absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full min-h-screen origin-top ${state}`}
        >
          <div
            ref={background}
            className="bg-slate-800/[.8] fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-full"
          />
          <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full">{children}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
  </Transition>
</SwitchTransition>
```